# How to draw connected strip lines in OpenGL like this

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glut, glu

I want to draw a series of connected lines (GL_LINE_STRIP) in following way.

[image: openGL Strip Lines]

I had tried to code by my own, but not get desired result, so i come here, help me to find out where i was wrong. here i am giving only my draw() function.

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

  glVertex2f(-4.00, 0.00);
  glVertex2f(-3.00, 2.00);
  glVertex2f(-2.00, 0.00);
  glVertex2f(-1.00, 2.00);
  glVertex2f(0.0, 0.00);
  glVertex2f(1.00, 2.00);
  glVertex2f(2.00, 0.00);
  glVertex2f(3.00, 2.00);
  glVertex2f(4.00, 0.00);

glEnd();
```

Comment: What are you seeing now? Try `glOrtho(-4.0,+4.0,-4.0,+4.0,-1.0,+1.0)` before drawing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Workin' perfectly here:

[image: lines]

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -6, 6, -6, 6, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3ub( 255, 255, 255 );
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    glVertex2f(-4.00, 0.00);
    glVertex2f(-3.00, 2.00);
    glVertex2f(-2.00, 0.00);
    glVertex2f(-1.00, 2.00);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.00);
    glVertex2f(1.00, 2.00);
    glVertex2f(2.00, 0.00);
    glVertex2f(3.00, 2.00);
    glVertex2f(4.00, 0.00);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```