# OpenGL 3.3 glDrawArrays for triangles

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I have to draw a height map and when I use: `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);` the program draws filled triangles. But I need only contours of triangles(3 lines). I tried almost every mode for `glDrawArray` (from [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml)) but there isn't appropriate solution.
Of course I can draw three lines for each triangle. But maybe is it possible to draw empty triangles in the better way?

Comment: (Solution by martin_pr is better) you could also use [line strips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554669/how-to-draw-connected-strip-lines-in-opengl-like-this)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you render primitives as wireframes in OpenGL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137629/how-do-you-render-primitives-as-wireframes-in-opengl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glPolygonMode.xml) to `GL_LINE`, that should do the trick.